# Declaração de array em javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Quando defino um objeto assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não aparesenta erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porem quando declaro que esse objeto é um array:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estoura esse erro de variavel indefinida:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: você não declarou que o objeto é um array

Answer (score 0):

Para definir o primeiro elemento de um array, no caso `cars[0]` você precisa primeiro declarar o array `cars = [];` ou `cars = new Array();`.

```js
var cars = [];
cars[0] = {
    a: "Saab",
    b: "Volvo",
    c: "BMW"
}
console.log(cars);

var cars2 = new Array();
cars2[0] = {
    a: "Saab",
    b: "Volvo",
    c: "BMW"
}
console.log(cars2);
```

Answer (score 0):

O erro é que não existe o array `cars`. Pode-se criá-lo dessa maneira:

```js
let cars = new Array({
    a: "Saab",
    b: "Volvo",
    c: "BMW"
});
console.log(cars);
```